# Check if a graph has exactly one cycle.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Design an efficient algorithm which given a directed graph G
in the adjacency-list representation, checks whether or not it is a single-cycle graph.
What is the fastest algorithm to do such a question?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you found an algorithm that does this already?

Comment: @Sudix I dont really know actually. Perhaps we can try DFS to search for a cycle. If found, continue the search for another one. If found, return false.

Comment: Using DFS to search for cycles is part of the recipe. Now if you just tweak this part: "If found, continue the search for another one", then you already have a linear time algorithm, as you just do a few DFS.